# Returning Grouped Data with Extra Row for each group in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have tables Composition, CompositionDetails and Tracks
Composition holds composition Name while compositionDetails is for mapping tracks with composition. One composition can have multiple tracks.

Table Structures are like this:

**Composition** table - CompositionId, CompositionName 
**Tracks** table - TrackId, TrackName 
**CompositionDetails** - CompositionId (FK), TrackId (FK)

Now with My query I am able to achieve this:

[image]

But I want this:

[image]

I mean one extra row above each group of composition. 
I achieved it creating temp tables and looping to insert extra row. But with millions to data, it is very slow.

Any suggestions on how can can achieve this without creating temp table and going over loop to insert new rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select Componame,TrackTitle from
(
Select Componame,TrackTitle,Componame as h,1 as Sort
from Composition
UNION 
Select Componame,Componame,MIN(Componame),0 as Sort
from Composition
group by Componame
) a
Order by h,Sort,Componame,TrackTitle
```

Comment: One `Componame` instance could certainly be spared. :) I'm sure if the subselect produced only the columns `Componame, TrackTitle, Sort`, you could then sort just by `Componame, Sort, TrackTitle`. Anyway, I think you've also over-simplified your answer, and without explaining, too, how the OP should go about using it with their *three* tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT c2.CompositionName, c2.CompositionName, c2.CompositionId
FROM Composition c2
UNION
SELECT c.CompositionName, t.TrackName, cd.CompositionId
FROM CompositionDetails cd join Composition c ON cd.CompositionId = c.CompositionId
JOIN Tracks t on t.Trackid = cd.Trackid
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `CompositionDetails` table doesn't have rows with NULLs in the `TrackId` column:

1. Using `UNION`, add one blank (NULL) `TrackId` per `CompositionId` into `CompositionDetails`.
2. Inner-join the resulting set to `Composition`.
3. Left-join the result of the inner join with `Tracks`. Obviously, this will yield NULL track names for the rows added in #1.
4. In the ORDER BY clause, sort by `CompositionName` first, then by `TrackName`. (In Transact-SQL, NULLs go before any values. Therefore, rows with blank track names will go before the others in their respective groups.)
5. In the SELECT clause, use either [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) or [`ISNULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) to replace blank track names with composition names.

```
SELECT
  c.CompositionName,
  COALESCE(t.TrackName, c.CompositionName)
FROM
  Composition AS c
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT          CompositionId, TrackId FROM CompositionDetails
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT CompositionId, NULL    FROM CompositionDetails
  ) AS d ON c.CompositionId = d.CompositionId
  LEFT JOIN Tracks AS t ON d.TrackId = t.TrackId
ORDER BY
  c.CompositionName,
  t.TrackName
;
```